# system.time and parallel package in R sys.child is 0

Tags: r, parallel-processing, profiling, doparallel

I would like to use system.time in R to get the total CPU time on a multicore function. The problem is that system.time does obviously not capture CPU time spend by the child processes spawned by the parallel package.

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParalllel(2)
timings <- system.time(foreach(i = 1:2) %do% rnorm(1e8))
```

Timings then looks like this

```
> timings
   user  system elapsed 
 16.883   5.731  22.899
```

The timings add up. Now if I use parallel processing:

```
timings <- system.time(foreach(i = 1:2) %dopar% rnorm(1e8))
> timings
   user  system elapsed 
  2.445   3.410  20.347
```

The user and system time are only capturing the master process. Specifically looking at the timings[4] and [5] shows me that the user.child and sys.child times are 0.

What do I have to do to measure total CPU time in R on parallel processing?

Note: Moving the cluster startup code into the system.time call did not make a difference.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

other attached packages:
[1] doParallel_1.0.10 iterators_1.0.8   foreach_1.4.3
```

Comment: check out `https://www.r-bloggers.com/the-wonders-of-foreach/`. the `user.child` column might be what you are looking for

Comment: You are right, the user.child column is the interesting one. But it's 0 in this case. What I learned from the link you shared (thanks!) and from testing this myself is that user.child and sys.child are populated when using doMC but not when using doParallel (neither in PSOCK nor in FORK mode). So is this simply not possible with the parallel package?

Answer (score 1):

@chinsoon12 pointed me in the right direction. user.child and sys.child are only populated when the cluster is created by registerDoParallel, e.g.

```
registerDoParalllel(cores = 2)
timings <- system.time(foreach(i = 1:2) %dopar% rnorm(1e8))

        user.self sys.self elapsed user.child sys.child
timings     0.429    1.978  19.378      9.818     1.386
```

This is why it worked out of the box with doMC where I did not manually start and stop the cluster via the cl variable.